# Nginx Vagrant Won't Restart

Tags: nginx, vagrant

Trying to set up a Vagrant Nginx server with a install script and this is what I have in my install script. Everything is working as expected until the restart command at the end.

```
# Install Nginx
add-apt-repository -y ppa:nginx/stable
apt-get update
apt-get install -y nginx

cat > /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain << EOF
upstream domain.local {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}

server {
    listen 0.0.0.0:80;
    server_name domain.local domain;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain.local.log;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://domain.local/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }
 }
EOF

# Turn off sendfile to be more compatible with Windows, which can't use NFS
sed -i 's/sendfile on;/sendfile off;/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/domain /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/domain

sudo service nginx restart
```

If I edit the sites-available file and change the values I can restart Nginx without a problem. However when it Vagrant is provisioning the VM with this install file I can't hit the server and can't get Nginx to restart. Am I missing something?

Comment: If this is using init.d scripts, you may need to "turn it on" with something like `sudo update-rc.d nginx defaults`.  This will link the startup scripts into the system startup list (assuming the `/etc/init.d/nginx` script is properly written).

Comment: Again this is a Vagrant provisioning script, this is the whole chunk of the Nginx part of the script. Nothing else is getting used and Nginx won't restart at the end of the script.

Answer (score 4):

Yes your missing that you do sudo and have no tty you need to configure the /etc/sudoers file to set your user to get not prompted for passwords ;) on sudo!

or try this

```
sudo clean=no service nginx restart
```

Comment: Is there a way to add a /etc/sudoers file when provisioning a VM with Vagrant? I tried the code snippet in the install script and Nginx still fails to restart.

Comment: you need to learn more about that sorry i can't help you with a quick tip at present about that. I am Coding a new tool that aims to replace vagrant will inform you

Answer (score 0):

Add following to your vagrant file in nginx machine section:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", run: "always", inline: "service nginx restart"
```